# Load rows of data from teradata tables to mysql tables

Tags: mysql, teradata

We have an situation where in  we need to load rows of data from teradata tables to mysql tables
any hint on how i could start with it?
canfastexport(or any other utility) help?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the volume of data you are talking about you have several options:

1. **BTEQ** can be used to export small to moderate data volumes and with some crafty SQL create delimited files using concatenation.
2. **FastExport** has a variety of flavors in which you can invoke it to export data from Teradata to a flat file. Teradata Studio and Studio Express should support JDBC based FastExports which can support moderate to large data volumes. Your bandwidth between Teradata and your desktop will dictate how feasible this is in reality. The standard FastExport utility leveraging the Teradata CLI is the fastest way to get data off the database and should be reserved for large data sets because the overhead for small data sets outweighs the speed advantages.
3. **Teradata Parallel Transport** is the replacement tool suite for the legacy MultiLoad/FastLoad/FastExport tools for Teradata. There are several operators such as STREAM that will allow you to pull data from the database to flat files.
4. **Leverage an enterprise ETL tool** that will use the FastExport or Teradata Parallel Transport API with Teradata to extract the data to the middle tier and then through mappings load the data into MySQL using the appropriate MySQL tool(s) to put the data away in staging tables or target tables.

Comment: hi Rob, Thank you for the details should it always be Teradata tables - flat/csv files - to my sql? can we not directly get data from teradata to my sql using any of the utilities you mentioned?

Comment: Using an ETL tool in the middle possibly. The native Teradata Utilities are meant to communicate with Teradata only and would not connect to MySQL.

Comment: we used fast export to get data in to csv..then used load data in file works smooth